# how to change the value of input type="text" when I start the keypress event in jquery?

Tags: html, input

Somebody help me about this problem. I want change the value of my input type text when I start pressing the keyboard. I had made this code. The value change but only 1 character I can write.

This is my code:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("input").keypress(function(){
            $("input[value='oldVal']").val("");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So it only changes once, the first time you press a key?

Answer (score 1):

Try This ...

```
<script>
   $(function(){
    $("input").onchange(function(){
        $("input[value='oldVal']").val("");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want to clear your text box.?

```
$(function(){

    $("input").keypress(function(){

        $(this).val("");

    });

});
```

or

```
$(function(){
    $("input").keypress(function(){
        $('input[name=inputName]').val("");
    });
});
```

Comment: You'll have the same issue with both of these. use `keyup`

Answer (score 0):

Its because its firing after your key goes down up, use `keyup`

```
$(function(){
    $("input").on('keyup', function(){
        $("input[value='oldVal']").val("");
    });
});
```